# Is there a way to set the IP configuration on a per network basis?

Tags: networking, wi-fi, dhcp

I connect to multiple wifi networks. On some of the networks I have to use a static IP address. Most with DHCP configurations are without the option to use static IP addressing.

For this reason I want to be able to set specific IP settings for the networks with special settings. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this natively in the settings of Android, as you've noticed.

However, there is an [app on the Android Market called "Wifi Static"](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.statIc) that should help you with what you're looking for.

Comment: I'd give you +2 if I could. I didn't know that they updated the website with the send to phone feature.